# Abstracting Hapi17 routes using async await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, hapi.js

I am trying to get my head around the move to await/async in Hapi 17.

Mainly I am trying to work out how to rewrite an abstracted route to one that will work with async/await

The following is an extract from my `routes\dogs.js` file

```
const DogController = require('../controllers/dog')
exports.plugin = {
  name: 'dogs',
  register: async (server, options) => {
    server.route({
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/api/dogs',
      handler: DogController.list
    })
```

With the relevant extract from `../controllers/dog`

```
exports.list = (req, h) => {
  return Dog.find({}).exec().then((dog) => {
    return { dogs: dog }
  }).catch((err) => {
    return { err: err }
  })
}
```

Which currently returns a list of dogs from a MongoDB database at the moment. I'd like to rewrite the route so that the handler becomes something like

```
handler: async (request, h) => {
          return DogController.list
        }
```

But I'm assuming that the Controller itself is what needs to change.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [options](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/API.md#route-options) property in Route that you can change the behavior of Route in request lifecycle. That means you can create an object and tie it up to your route definition.

Here is your dogs.js route plugin.

```
exports.plugin = {
    async register(server, options) {
        const DogController = require('../controllers/dogs');
        server.route([
            {
                method: 'GET',
                path: '/dogs',
                options: DogController.view
            },                
        ]);
    },
    name: 'dogs-route'
};
```

And here, your dog controller.

```
exports.view = {
    description: 'list all the good dogs',
    handler: async (request, h) => {
        return h.view('index', {'title': 'Home Page Title'});
        try {
            const dogs = await Dog.find({}).exec();
            return {dogs};
        }
        catch(e){
            // or something you want
            return Boom.badRequest(e.message, e);
        }
    }
};
```

[Here](https://github.com/metoikos/hapi-moon/blob/master/app/controllers/main.js) is a full example that you can check both routes and controllers respectively.